# Finding the vector $\vec c$ directed along the bisector of the angle between the vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ where $|\vec c|=\sqrt 2$

Tags: vectors

> **Problem :**
>
> Find the vector $\vec{c}$ directed along the bisector of the angle between the vectors $\vec{a}=\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ and $\vec{b}=2\hat{i}-\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ where $|\vec{c}|=\sqrt{2}$

Please suggest how to proceed in such problems , no idea how to find bisector of angle, however done in straight lines but not in vectors. please suggest will be of great help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comsider the unit vectors $$\hat{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$
And  $$\hat{b}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then the vector in the direction either internally or externally bisecting the angle between $a$ and $b$ is parallel to $$\hat{a}\pm\hat{b}$$

So you can calculate either of these, divide by the modulus and multiply by $\sqrt{2}$ and you have what you want.